# Simulate user clicking out of a field programably

Tags: php, jquery

I have searched for days and tried several resolutions. None are working. I'm a little new to this, so please bear with me.  I’m using PHP, Jquery, and Mysql. The Mysql is not relevant.

Using PHP, I have a request `form` that a user fills out. As they leave, an `input[type=“number”]` a `$function({})` is called that does some calculations based on the value in `input[type=“number”]` and then populates the results in `#test-id.text()`, e.g., `<div id=“test-id”></div>`.

When the `form` is submitted to the Mysql database, only the `input` fields are saved, not the calculated results, values stored in `#test-id.text()`.

When the user searches for this request, the `input` fields are populated using

```
<input type=“number” id=“test-1” name=“test-1” value=“<?php echo $test1;?>”>
```

How do I now simulate the element losing focus so the calculations run?

This is one attempt that I was hoping would work.

```
<div>
  <input id="test-1" type="number" name="test-1" value="10">
  <script> 
    $('#test-1').click(function() {
      $('#test-1').trigger(click);
    }); 
  </script>
</div>
<div>test results: </div><span id="test-2"></span>
```

The **`value=10`** comes from the database and `<?php echo $test1; ?>`
I have tried `$(“#test-1’).blur()` and `$(“#test-1’).click()`, the two most popular solutions, but none are working.

I’ve thought about saving the values in `#test-id.text()`, but there are many of them, and the calculations would return the same results every time.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue including relevant html and js code so we can see precisely what the situation is and what "not working" might actually mean in practice. Disconnected snippets of code do not allow us to fully assess the situation. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post, and then we might be able to help you. Thanks

Comment: P.S. You might not actually need to simulate the user clicking. If you simply execute the calculation function directly, that would suffice. Or if the calculation is reasonably simple, you could re-implement it in PHP and echo the result.

Comment: Move the code that does the calculations into it's own `function doCalculations() {` then call this when the page loads.   Without seeing your code, it's hard to give a specific code answer.

Comment: I edited the portion of what I wanted to do.

I can't create the doCalculations() function on page load without completely rewriting the called functions.  Pretend you are filling out a form, and you type in the number 10 to represent how many miles you ran.  As soon as you exit out of that field, a function calculates you burned 1,000 calories and displays this in #id.text(). You click save.

You want to review your results, and open the form and the database populates your inputs.  I am using PHP's `echo` to restore your saved inputs.

I now need to emulate the field losing focus.

Comment: Edited my question to better show what I'm trying to do.

This is the .blur() function called when the user tabs out of the field.
`$("#test-1").blur(function() {  //run calculations });`

Comment: Thanks.  `$('#test-1').click(function()` listens and waits for the user to click. So if you want to simulate a click when the page loads, don't put `$('#test-1').trigger(click)` inside the listener! Also it would need to be `$('#test-1').trigger("click")`, or $('#test-1').trigger("blur");` if you want to simulate blur. Note the quote marks, you need to pass it a literal string

Comment: @ADyson - I got the .blur() to work.  Thanks!!

Comment: Great. Feel free to post your final code as an Answer then others might learn from it in future (and get you some upvotes) :-). See also [answer]

Comment: The fix was triggering .blur().  After the `input` I added the following: 


`<script> $(function() {$("#test-1").trigger('blur');});</script>`

Comment: Ok but, again, you need to write that in the "Answer" section in the box below this. Comments are not searchable and cannot be voted on, and to the search, your question still appears to be unanswered! Take the [tour] if you're not sure how Stackoverflow's system works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Triggering the .blur() function worked.  I added the `script` tag after the `input` tag, and it simulated the user tabbing out of, or clicking away from, the `input` field, triggering my calculations.

```
    <div>
      <input id="test-1" type="number" name="test-1" value="<?php echo $floorArea1;?>">
      <script> $(function() {$("#test-1").trigger('blur');});</script>
   </div>
```